# Adding a layer stored in a PostGIS database to an OpenLayers map as a clickable vector layer via GeoServer

Tags: openlayers, wms, vector

I can view a layer (called wmsSource), created as a vector point-set, and stored in a PostGIS table from an Esri shapefile, in my OpenLayers map, as a WMS Image layer, using this code, a modification from the OpenLayers sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>WMS GetFeatureInfo (Image Layer)</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
    <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
    <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/build/ol.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <div id="info">&nbsp;</div>
    <script>
  
    var geosource = new ol.source.ImageWMS({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Workspace/wms',
        params: {'LAYERS': 'Workspace:Shapefile layers for the Bay of Plenty'},
        ratio: 1,
        serverType: 'geoserver'
    });

    var geolayer = new ol.layer.Image ({source: geosource,});

    var view = new ol.View({
        center: [19687000, -4573021],
        zoom: 11
      });

      var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [geolayer],
        target: 'map',
        view: view
      });

      map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
        document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = '';
        var viewResolution = /** @type {number} */ (view.getResolution());
        var url = geosource.getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
            evt.coordinate, viewResolution, 'EPSG:3857',
            {'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html'});
        if (url) {
          document.getElementById('info').innerHTML =
              '<iframe seamless src="' + url + '"></iframe>';
        }
      });

      map.on('pointermove', function(evt) {
        if (evt.dragging) {
          return;
        }
        var pixel = map.getEventPixel(evt.originalEvent);
        var hit = map.forEachLayerAtPixel(pixel, function() {
          return true;
        });
        map.getTargetElement().style.cursor = hit ? 'pointer' : '';
      });

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The example displays all the data as an image in a frame (although Firefox blocks the image as an inset and forces me to open it in another tab), but I would like to be able to click an item on the map and get a pop-up of information, just the `fid` would be a start.

The layer covers a small area, so native SRS used is EPSG:2106.

What is the syntax I should use to get data from the `fid` field into `innerHTML` for a pop-up?

Comment: Shapefiles are not stored in PostGIS databases. The data *from* a shapefile may be loaded into a PostgreSQL database, with the geometry stored in a PostGIS `geometry` type, but at that point it is no longer a shapefile.

Comment: That should be possible with WMS https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/getfeatureinfo-image.html  The data may also be available as GeoJSON via WFS but you would need to style a vector layer yourself.

Comment: That has clarified things - I was able to see the full table of information using the OpenLayers example suggested by Mike. Now I have to work out how to extract individual field data and return them as constants for the pop-up.

Comment: If the source supports it `{'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/json'}` will return the feature in GeoJSON format.

Comment: I've played around with {'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/json'} without success. I did get the table error to appear in a popup, but have not been able to get the popup to move to the click location, it remains stubbornly stuck in the bottom left corner.
I know I can click on a feature and get a response, so now I need to get a 'Hello World' pop-up in the right location.
To extract the data I'm going no need to find, and study a sample script that works. All the snippets I've tried from various sources, when inserted and modified have, so far,  failed.

Comment: It should be possible by combining the FeatureInfo example with the Popup example.  If `application/json` is not supported you could try `test/plain` and then extract field data using regular expressions.  https://codesandbox.io/s/getfeatureinfo-image-forked-7hs4pi?file=/main.js

Comment: Thanks Mike, I played around with your code, but as soon as I link to my WMS layer the overlay.setPosition(evt.coordinate)  seems to fail and the popup hides back in the corner. I suspect that the correct coordinates are not being collected on the click event. I tried to get a simple 'Hello World' to work - but I just have an empty popup in the corner.

Comment: One step forward - if I remove  'EPSG:3857', or replace it with 'EPSG:2106' (the native crs of the layer)  - refresh and wait about ten seconds, the mouse pointer responds to the pointer function. If I zoom in and out, it no longer responds, even if I wait. No pop-ups at all.